# trying to resolve this compilation error, caused by split method string[] cannot be converted to string

Tags: java, compiler-errors

the task here is to create a file, create a object called Student that takes a name, age gpa. the file is filled with lines that look roughly like this name=Jane Robinson,age=19,gpa=3.81 while reading each line i am to split the "," and the "=" and then check each index of array for "name", "age", "gpa" if one of those are found, to then substring(startpostion, rest of string); and save that as a variable, call the Student setters for each variable and set them, then load the newly set up Student objects into a arrayList called result, that I may then return it.

the current error is this here

```
./StudentReader.java:41: error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
       string2[i] = string1[i].split("=");
                                    ^
1 error
```

code here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * 
 *
 *
 *
 */
public class StudentReader {
  public static Student[] readFromTextFile(String fileName) {
  ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();
   String name =" ";
   int age = 0;
   double gpa = 0.0;
   String fill;
   
   File f = new File(fileName);
   Scanner n;
   try
   {
       n = new Scanner(f);
   }
  catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
   {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   while (n.hasNextLine())
   {
     fill = n.nextLine();
     Student g =  new Student(name , age, gpa);
     String[] string1 = fill.split(",");
     
     String[] string2 = new String[string1.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < string1.length; ++i)
     {
       
       string2[i] = string1[i].split("=");
      if (string2[i].substring(0,4).equals("name"))
        {
      name = string2[i].substring(4,string2[i].length());
        }
      if(string2[i].substring(0,3).equals("age"))
        {
      age = Integer.parseInt(string2[i].substring(3,string2[i].length()));
        }
      if(string2[i].substring(0,3).equals("gpa"))
        {
      gpa = Double.parseDouble(string2[i].substring(3,string2[i].length()));
        }
        
     }
   } 
    return result.toArray(new Student[0]);
  }
}
```

and here is the line that is throwing the error:

```
string2[i] = string1[i].split("=");
```

here im trying to take a new array here called string2 and assign it to the array string1 after it splits each string object inside the array string1 by the = sign, but i am unsure on how to resolve this, as ive never seen this error before, and my knowledge is very little when it comes to this, does anyone know a workaround here?

this is where string2 array is declared

```
 String[] string2 = new String[string1.length];
```

i think i resolved it here

```
string2 = string1[i].split("=");
im not longer throwing a error with this
```

Comment: We can tell you why the problem exists, but we don't have enough information to suggest a workaround.

Comment: You are trying to return a String[] into a String object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String split method returns all the matching conditions elements in an array. Hence you should use the for-loop as below :

```
while (n.hasNextLine()) {
   
     fill = n.nextLine();
     Student g =  new Student(name , age, gpa);
     String[] string1 = fill.split(",");

     for (int i = 0; i < string1.length; ++i) {
         String[] temp = string1[i].split("=");
         if (temp[i].substring(0,4).equals("name")) {
             name = temp[i].substring(4,temp[i].length());
         } else if(temp[i].substring(0,3).equals("age")) {
             age = Integer.parseInt(temp[i].substring(3,temp[i].length()));
         } else if(temp[i].substring(0,3).equals("gpa")) {
             gpa = Double.parseDouble(temp[i].substring(3,temp[i].length()));
         }            
      }
}
```

Use else-if to avoid multiple if executions.